# Заданы массивы А и В, содержащие n и m элементов соответственно. Вставить массив В между k-м и (k + 1)-м элементами массива А (k задано). VBA

Tags: массивы, vba

Возникли трудности при решении данной задачи, выводит не совсем верный результат. Почему-то после объединения массивов A и B не выводит остаточные значения массива A. Заранее спасибо.

```
Sub n215()
Dim i As Double, k As Double, A(1 To 10) As Double, B(1 To 10) As Double
For i = 1 To 6
A(i) = Cells(i, 1)
Next
For i = 1 To 4
B(i) = Cells(i, 2)
Next
k = 4
For i = 1 To 4
k = k + 1
A(k) = B(i)
Next i
For i = 1 To k
Cells(i, 3) = A(i)
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Немого не дожали )

Вставить между... Это значит: взять `k` значений массива `А`, дописать значения массива `В`, ниже дописать значения масива `А`, начиная с `k + 1` с до последнего. Но как? Ни в массив А, ни в массив В значения двух массивов не поместятся... Да просто - создать третий массив С, задав его размерность

```
ReDim C_(1 To n + m, 1 To 1)
```

а после заполнения выгрузить на лист:

```
Cells(1, 3).Resize(UBound(C_), 1).Value = C_
```

Двумерный - потому что одномерный массив горизонтальный, его можно записать на лист в одну строку. Чтобы записать в столбец, его придется или транспонировать, или значения в ячейки записывать в цикле (а это плохо, т.к. обращение к объектам листа - медленная операция).

[Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1215474/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2) показывал, как исходные массивы заполнять диапазоном значений за один раз, без цикла.

Дальше пробуйте сами.

Ответ будет дополнен, но через несколько дней. Надо же дать студенту возможность подумать и получить зачет самостоятельно:)

Comment: Спасибо конечно, была мысль добавить третий массив, но не получилось. А решить через одномерные массивы нельзя? Двумерные я ещё не изучал...

Comment: Можно и через одномерные. `ReDim C_(1 To n + m)`. Как заполнять одномерные и выгружать данные на лист, Вы знаете.